# How do I use the for-each loop to scan through an int array object?

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop

if I create a new int array object using `new` like below:

```
int *array = new int[20];
```

and fill the array with some integers, then attempting to scan through that array with a for-each loop will throw me an error:

```
for (int x : array)  // error
```

why does this happen and how can I fix it? I tried playing around with the referencer and address notations (`*` and `&`) but every combination I tried fails.

ex.

```
for (int &x : *array)  // does not work either.
```

Comment: Use `std::vector` or `std::array`.

Comment: Hi Jarod42, as much as I would love to, I can't use those particular types for the exercise I'm working on.

Comment: Whenever you post code which has an error, please post the error message you get - sometimes this is incredibly useful to people trying to answer your question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`array` is *not* an array, but a pointer, which can't be used for [Range-based for loop](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for), because there's no information about the size of the "array", the `begin` and `end` of the "array" can't be deduced.

> range_expression  -   any expression that represents a suitable
>   sequence (either an array or an object for which begin and end member
>   functions or free functions are defined, see below) or a
>   braced-init-list.

You might make it real array, (or use `std::array` instead of the raw array)

```
int array[20];
for (int x : array) { processing with x... }
```

Or write the loop manually:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) { processing with array[i]... }
```

Answer (score 2):

in `for (int x : array)`, it requires that `begin(array)` and `end(array)` are valid. which is not for `int*`.

it would work for `int array[20]`, `std::vector`, `std::array<int, 20>`.